# How to pass System property to docker containers?

Tags: java, docker

So I know you can pass Environment variables to a docker container using -e like:

```
docker run -it -e "var=var1" myDockerImage
```

But I need to pass a System Property to a docker container, because this is how I run my JAR:

```
java -Denvironment=dev -jar myjar.jar
```

So how can I pass a -D System property in Docker? Like:

```
docker run -it {INSERT Denvironment here} myDockerImage
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the variable you passed into the container on the java command:

```
docker run -it -e "ENV=dev" myDockerImage
java -Denvironment=$ENV -jar myjar.jar
```

Answer (score 6):

One more way to do it, if running under Tomcat, is setting your system variables in your Dockerfile using `ENV JAVA_OPTS` like this:

```
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:/tomcatDev.jks -D_WS_URL=http://some/url/"
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

One can also use the following `start.sh` ENTRYPOINT for the Docker container, make sure to use the array syntax, e.g.:

*Dockerfile:*

```
...
ENTRYPOINT ["/start.sh"]
```

The actual *start.sh* script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
exec $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar myjar.jar $@
```

Then you can just pass the Java system properties directly to your application as docker run container arguments:

```
docker run myDockerImage "-Dvar=var1"
```

Comment: I suspect this doesn't work (tested in oracle jdk) because something like: java -jar app.jar -Dvar=value will not be a System property. It will be passed as an argument. To be a system property it should be: java -Dvar=value -jar app.jar

Comment: just tested and matias is correct, this answer will not work. it should be `exec $JAVA_HOME/bin/java $@ -jar myjar.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Have a `start.sh` file, e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
exec java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom $* -jar /app.jar
```

In your Dockerfile:

```
...
COPY start.sh /start.sh
RUN chmod a+rx /start.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/start.sh"]
```